# Partitioning the Boot section of the hdd

Tags: partitioning

So ...I built my 12 year old a computer;  I loaded Ubuntu 12 on it.  This has been in use for the last few months.  However my Son now wants Windows and wants Ubuntu completely gone. With that in  mind, I pulled out my Windows 7 disc and inserted it.  The installation screen comes up and I click "install".  Temporary files screen comes up then it stopped with an error code saying there is no room in my boot partition to place the files and that 837 mb is needed.  So I go into the Ubuntu menu and open the partition manager.  The root partition shows that it is locked and cannot be changed or resized.  So that is my question:  How do I resize the root partition in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Boot your original Ubuntu install media and run the "Try" option.  Open a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-t) and run your partition program from that.  When the disk is in use, partition changes are wisely locked out.

Comment: If you do not want dual boot, just erase all of Ubuntu. Windows installer need either a blank disk or a primary NTFS partition with the boot flag to install into.